# Default Value in PHP For Loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have a HTML select form to select the day/month/year, and this is generated with PHP.  My for loop, for example with the month, looks like this:

```
$html="<select name=\"".$name."month\">";       
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
 {$html.="<option value='$i'>$months[$i]</option>";}
$html.="</select> ";
```

I can't seem to figure out how to set a "default" value to the current month while retaining all of the prior months in the dropdown (I can just set $i=date("n"), but then I lose the ability to select any prior month).

Does anybody know a simple way of setting the default value to be the current day?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't choose the javascript method because of support and speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$currentMonth = date("m");

$html = "<select name=\"" . $name . "month\">";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if ($i == $currentMonth) {
        $html .= "<option selected='selected' value='$i'>$months[$i]</option>";
    } else {
        $html .= "<option value='$i'>$months[$i]</option>";
    }
}
$html .= "</select> ";

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: I'm sure it was quite easy, but for someone that barely knows PHP, I couldn't figure it out with an hour of troubleshooting.  Nothing game up in Google for "default value in for loop".

Thank you very much for this answer!

Comment: @paul i wanted to say, if i had answered before him, i would have got +1 . i know it's childish nature dying for +1 but i have this nature